# How to map audio to target text transcription

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, speech-to-text

I am new to deep learning, I am making a basic end to end voice recognizer using tensorflow API, LSTM model and ctc loss function. I have extracted my audio features to mfccs. i don't really know how to map my audios to transcriptions, i know ctc is use for the purpose, I know how ctc works but don't know the code to implement it.

Here is my code to extract features

```
import os
import numpy as np
import glob
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
from python_speech_features import mfcc, logfbank

# Read the input audio file
for f in glob.glob('Downloads/DataVoices/Training/**/*.wav', recursive=True):
    (rate,sig) = wav.read(f)
    sig = sig.astype(np.float64)
    # Take the first 10,000 samples for analysis
    #sig = sig[:10000]
    mfcc_feat = mfcc(sig,rate,winlen=0.025, winstep=0.01,
                     numcep=13, nfilt=26, nfft=512, lowfreq=0, highfreq=None,
                     preemph=0.97, ceplifter=22, appendEnergy=True)
    fbank_feat = logfbank(sig, rate)
    acoustic_features = np.concatenate((mfcc_feat, fbank_feat), axis=1) # time_stamp x n_features
    print(acoustic_features)
```

I have also made a training list.txt file  where i have provided transcriptions with audio path like:

this is example/001/001.wav

this is example/001/001(1).wav

where 001 is folder and 001.wav and 0001(1).wav are two wave files of one utterance.

Comment: Could you clarify your question ? Where is the transcript ?

Comment: I have edited my question, it may now be clear to you, and if not please let me know.

Comment: I have an example that executes. But you have to add your functionality and also verify the batch sizes etc. This is a bare minimum example.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this as a *contrived* example assuming that this would give an idea of how a CSV file and filenames inside the CSV can be read. You could modify this to suit your needs.

Let's say I have this CSV file. The first column is your transcript. The file path is your audio file. In my case it is just a text file with random text.

```
Script1,D:/PycharmProjects/TensorFlow/script1.txt
Script2,D:/PycharmProjects/TensorFlow/script2.txt
```

This is the code I use to test it. Please remember this is an example.

```
import tensorflow as tf


batch_size = 1
record_defaults = [ ['Test'],['D:/PycharmProjects/TensorFlow/script1.txt']]


def readbatch(data_queue) :

    reader = tf.TextLineReader()
    _, rows = reader.read_up_to(data_queue, batch_size)
    transcript,wav_filename = tf.decode_csv(rows, record_defaults,field_delim=",")
    audioreader = tf.WholeFileReader()
    print(wav_filename)
    _, audio = audioreader.read( tf.train.string_input_producer(wav_filename) )
    return [audio,transcript]

data_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(['D:\\PycharmProjects\\TensorFlow\\script.csv'], shuffle=False)

batch_data = readbatch(data_queue)

batch_values = tf.train.batch(batch_data, shapes=[tf.TensorShape(()),tf.TensorShape(batch_size,)],  batch_size=batch_size, enqueue_many=False )

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    sess.run(tf.initialize_local_variables())
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    try:
        step = 0
        while not coord.should_stop():
            step += 1
            feat = sess.run([batch_values])
            audio = feat[0][0]
            print(audio)
            script = feat[0][1]
            print(script)
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        print(' training for 1 epochs, %d steps', step)
    finally:
        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
```